# jQuery appends a paragraph twice

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a jquery animation and weirdly, when I append a new paragraph, it appends it twice, the problem only happens when 2 previous paragraphs are appended, probably that's a jQuery bug.. otherwise, I hope someone can help me.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="element">
     </div>
</body>​
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    animation();
});

function animation()
{
   $('<p id="p1">paragraph 1</p>').appendTo('#element');
   $('<p id="p2">paragraph 2</p>').appendTo('#element');
   $('#p1, #p2').fadeOut(600, function(){
       $('#p1, #p2').remove();
       var $p3 = $('<p>paragraph 3 </p>').appendTo('#element');
   });
}​
```

The problem is with "paragraph 3" that is appended twice!
You can run the code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jonah13/QLM2s/

Thanks,
Younes

Comment: Thanks for the jsFiddle in the Q - makes our lives easier!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why other answers that identified the problem were down-voted, since they identified the problem.

Here is the code to fix it. Note from the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/promise), that as of jQuery 1.6 (which I assume you're using since the jsFiddle was using 1.7.2) you can use `.promise()`:

> As of jQuery 1.6, the `.promise()` method can be used in conjunction with the `deferred.done()` method to execute a single callback for the animation as a whole when all matching elements have completed their animations.

I've updated your fiddle:

```
$(function() {
   animation();
});

function animation()
{
   $('<p id="p1">paragraph 1</p>').appendTo('#element');
   $('<p id="p2">paragraph 2</p>').appendTo('#element');
   $('#p1, #p2')
     .fadeOut(600)
     .promise().done(function() {
       $('#p1, #p2').remove();
       var $p3 = $('<p>paragraph 3 </p>').appendTo('#element');
   });         
}​
```

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen promise() before.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem and I learned a couple new things

Comment: @jonah13: If this solved your problem, you might want to un-accept the answer I gave and mark this one...

Comment: Once I figured out what the problem is, there were dozens of ways to solve the problem, but yes, this answer is the best if you don't want to change any behavior in the script!

Answer (score 5):

The function provided to `fadeOut()` is fired once per element which matches the selector. Since the selector returns two elements it is fired twice, thus appending two paragraphs.

Modified example here: http://jsfiddle.net/QLM2s/1/

Comment: No idea why this was down-voted - this is indeed the problem.

Comment: YES, That totally makes sense, I fixed the problem! Thank you!!

Comment: Added an answer that uses `promise()` (jQuery 1.6+ - assumed OK since jsFiddle was using 1.7.2) - I personally think this is a cleaner and more maintainable solution.

Comment: @RobCooper - I like your answer; I haven't used `promise()` before but it looks like the elegant way to handle this scenario.

Comment: @TimMedora Glad you like it. I've not used it much, but agree it's pretty elegant.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is where fade out paragraphs 1 and 2: jQuery is executing the code inside the fade-out function for every selector you give it (in this case, two paragraphs so two appends).

Comment: No idea why this was down-voted - this is indeed the problem.

Comment: @Rob Cooper: Agreed. Down votes really should come with an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Since fadeout() is firing twice better you empty the paragraph before append to div.

Try below code:

```
$(function() {
 animation();
});
function animation() 
{
 $('<p id="p1">paragraph 1</p>').appendTo('#element');
 $('<p id="p2">paragraph 2</p>').appendTo('#element');
 $('#p1, #p2').fadeOut(600, function(){      
      $('p').empty();
   var $p3 = $('<p>paragraph 3 </p>').appendTo('#element');
 });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work fine

```
$(function() {
   animation();
});

function animation()
{
   $('<p id="p1">paragraph 1</p>').appendTo('#element');
   $('<p id="p2">paragraph 2</p>').appendTo('#element');
   $('#p1').fadeOut(600, function(){
       $('#p1').fadeOut();
      $('#p1, #p2').remove();
      var $p3 = $('<p>paragraph 3 </p>').appendTo('#element');
   }
```

);
}​

Comment: Assume fading out `p1` again was a typo. But this would not fade them out at the same time.